# Shortest a -> b -> (a -> b) function in Haskell

Tags: code-golf, functional-programming, haskell

I got the following question at a test:

> Write a function `f` with the following type `a -> b -> (a -> b)`. `a` and `b` should not be bound in any sense, the shorter the code, the better.

I came up with `f a b = \x -> snd ([a,x],b)`. Can you find something tinier?

**Currently the winner is: `f _=(.f).const`**

Comment: If a more general type is allowed: `f = const const`.

Comment: @hammar: or `f _ b _ = b`, but, given the solution in the question, I suspect a more general type is *not* allowed.

Comment: If a more general type is allowed, why not `f = id`?

Comment: In fact if a more general type is allowed then `f = f` is a solution, so I guess the conditions on the type are very important!

Comment: A more general type is not allowed, your assumptions were correct.

Comment: If you're allowed to import Control.Applicative, you can replace `const` by `pure`, which is one character less.

Comment: Can the answer be a partial function?

Answer (score 12):

Your example can be shrunk by getting rid of the anonymous function on the right-hand side:

```
f a b x = snd ([a,x],b)
```

This works because the type `a -> b -> a -> b` is equivalent to `a -> b -> (a -> b)` in Haskell.

Comment: Slightly shorter modification: `f a b x = snd (f x,b)`

Answer (score 5):

The function `f _=(.f).const` is actually of a more general type than `f :: a -> b -> (a -> b)`, namely `f :: a -> b -> (c -> b)`. If no type signature is given, the type inference system infers a type of `f :: a -> b -> (a -> b)`, but if you include the type signature `f :: a -> b -> (c -> b)` with the exact same definition, Haskell will compile it without issue and will report consistent types for the partial applications of f. There is probably some deep reason why the type inference system is stricter than the type checking system in this case, but I don't understand enough category theory to come up with a reason as to why this should be the case. If you are unconvinced, you are welcome to try it yourself.

Comment: might be like the case of `f a b = f a a`. it infers to be of type `a -> a -> b` although it complies with the type `a -> b -> c`. it is because if `f` is not given a type it can only use itself monomorphically.

Comment: i don't think this should matter though

Answer (score 4):

Given `ScopedTypeVariables`, I came up with this:

```
f (_::a) b (_::a) = b
```

If you shrink down both my function and yours, mine is a hair shorter:

```
f(_::a)b(_::a)=b
f a b x=snd([a,x],b)
```

Of course, you're probably not allowed to rely on `ScopedTypeVariables` :P.

Comment: This is not as short as `f _=(.f).const` ([due to Sassa NF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21752250/shortest-a-b-a-b-function-in-haskell)). Which also doesn't need `ScopedTypeVariables`.

Comment: Hmm, I initially thought this would require the first and third arguments to be lists...

Comment: @ChrisTaylor: Too much OCaml on the mind? :)

Comment: Hah, must be! ;)